# Httpcontext.request("") is returing null values in ashx handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

am posting some data to my ashx handler in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The httpcontext.request.params is showing empty values. I don't know what is wrong. Here's my code and am pretty sure i have posted the keys and values in Postman rest client.

```
     <%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="Repository" %>

    Imports System
     Imports System.Web
     Imports System.IO

    Public Class Repository : Implements IHttpHandler
Private Shared cp_merchant_id As String = "e7204ccb734bac3fdf937124448acb6c"
Private Shared cp_ipn_secret As String = "Prodigy1234"
Private Shared cp_debug_email As String = "dipad10@rocketmail.com"
Private Shared order_total As String = "0.0102"
Private txn_id As String, item_name As String, item_number As String, amount1 As Double, amount As Double, amount2 As Double, currency1 As String, _
currency2 As String, status As Integer, status_text As String, email As String, custom As String
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest



    If context.Request("ipn_mode") = "" Then
        context.Response.Write("An Error Occured")
        Exit Sub
    End If

        If context.Request("merchant") = "" Or context.Request("merchant") <> Trim(cp_merchant_id) Then

            context.Response.Write("No or incorrect Merchant ID passed")
            Exit Sub
        End If


    'validate if the malicious person doesnt know the ipnmode

    'this means either button,cart,deposit, and so on
    txn_id = context.Request("txn_id")
    item_name = context.Request("item_name")
    item_number = context.Request("item_number")
    amount1 = context.Request("amount1")
    amount2 = context.Request("amount2")
    currency1 = context.Request("currency1")
    currency2 = context.Request("currency2")
    status = context.Request("status")
    status_text = context.Request("status_text")
    email = context.Request("email")
    custom = context.Request("custom")
    'check against order total

    'If amount1 < order_total Then
    '    Response.Write("Amount cannot be lesser than 0.01015 BTC")
    '    Exit Sub
    'End If
    Dim commission As Double = 0.00015

    'check status
    If status >= 100 Or status = 2 Then
        'means payment is complete save data and send mail saying transaction successful

    ElseIf status < 0 Then
        'payment error, this is usually final but payments will sometimes be reopened if there was no exchange rate conversion or with seller consent 
        context.Response.Write("Payment Error")
    Else
        'payment is pending, you can optionally add a note to the order page 
        context.Response.Write("Payment Pending")
    End If


End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Please make sure `Content-Type` is set as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in *header*, and values are placed in *body* as Key Value pairs.

```
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

*(Click on images to view actual size)*
[image]

[image]

Comment: I did the same thing still returning "Nothing'', where can i upload aa screen shot

Comment: Can i see your web config probably there could be something missing in mine

Comment: It is just a blank ASP.NET Web Form project. You could create a new one, and test the above code.

Comment: it worked on a blank project... but not on my main project

Comment: Well, at least you know your handler code is working. Now, you will need to create a new project, and move one feature at a time from old project, so that you know what the problem is. *If this answer solved the original problem that you asked, please mark it as **Answer**. It'll help the community.*